# Jquery-UI issue with Primefaces

Tags: jquery, primefaces

There is a need of using jquery tab and jquery date picker in my module. I have used the jquery.js and jquery-plugin.js from primefaces bundle but I can't create tab and date picker. So I included only Jquery-UI.js only in my module(not in template). All the modules work's fine until they enter into my module. Once they enter into my module(where I have included the Jquery-UI.js) and navigate to other module some functionality is not working. even though I am not getting any browser console error. But primeface dialog is not working. I am using primeface jquery along with jquery-ui included in my module.

Comment: Never manually include a jquery.js or jquery-ui.js in a page that might also be used in a page with PF components. And _'All the modules work's fine until they enter into my module.'_ is sort of vague, as is your title. Can you improve the question, also by creating a [mcve] that focusses on _' but I can't create tab and date picker.'_...

Comment: Hi. Using jquery-plugins from primeface bundle I cant create tabs.Which means i cant use the below lines
 jQuery("#ID").tabs(); getting error that tabs() is not defined. so i used jquery-ui.js in my module(Which the jquery provides. not from primeface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solved Jquery UI Conflict issue with Primeface.*** 
I have used 3 Jquery UI component, 
1. Jquery Tab.
2. Jquery Draggable.
3. Jquery Calender.

while using this together I got this issue. Then I tried removing the component one by one and found that ***Jquery-Calendar is having some problem with Primeface-Jquery***. So I removed the jquery calendar and used browser calendar with  `<input type='calendar' >`

Comment: What do you mean by _"So I removed the jquery calendar and used plain "_?